# Setting Width & Height with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with my page content looking way too small.  I have messed around with every selector i can but can't seem to make my content appear normally.  I would like my page to be accessable on most devices and browsers.  My CSS:

```
body, h1, h2, h3, p, header, {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: #efeff3;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  clear:both;
  margin:  auto auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("img/cube.png");
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  background-image: url("img/cube.png");
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px 0  0;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: tomato;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
}

.nav {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 5px 0;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
  padding: 0 10px 15px 10px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
}

.main-content{
  margin: 80px 0 0 0;
}

.blog {
  background: #fff;
  padding:50px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  border: 5px ridge;
}

.blog h2 {
  font-size:21px;
  font-weight:500;
}

.blog h2 a {
  color:#CC0000;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.blog .date {
  color:#9e9e9e;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-size:14px;
}

.blog .text {
  color:#212121;
  margin-top:20px;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:22px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

p#copyright {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

img.mediaicon {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px auto 20px;
  background-image: url("img/cube.png");
}
```

Comment: What are we supposed to do with that?

Comment: Please try to include all relevant code, here and maybe in jsfiddle so we can see what is happening.  Without context, your CSS means very little.

Comment: Not to mention that 50% of that CSS is invalid - there are no spaces around the dashes in selectors such as *(but not limited to)* `background-image`, `text-align`, `margin-left`, etc.  @dippas Editing out his CSS mistakes might actually make the question invalid - the problem might have been his old CSS (with spaces) in the first place.

Comment: I tried to post a screenshot but I don't have any score.  I thought the classes spoke for themselves but I can post the html if that is what you need.  I figured out how to make it work well enough I'm sure I'll pick up on it eventually.  For some reason html & css are harder than serious languages to me

Comment: Yeah I see my question was very broad and you guys had nothing to go on really.  It was like 5 am I should have just went to bed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but reading your CSS, your spacings are invalid. You cannot separate numbers from measures, like:

```
20 px
```

Must be:

```
20px
```